# How to make Finder ALWAYS show one window on Get Info

Tags: finder

If I press <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> on a file in Finder it brings up one window with details about that file.

If I do the same with 50 files, Finder opens one window.

But if I select 10 files and press press <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> I get 10 windows.

How do I tell my computer to always open one 'Get Info' window, regardless of how many files are selected?

*Example of what I don't want*
[image]

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>  Will open only one "Get Info" Window in Finder and that window will display only the currently selected Finder item.  Selecting a different item will display that new item's info in that already opened "Get Info" window.

If you have 10 Finder items selected, the 1 "Get Info" window will show basic info on the 10 selected items.